# set_shape raising problems in read_and_decode with TFRecordReader in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to train an imagenet classifier with my own architecture (the pretrained weights are needed for my project). I have preprocessed the images of ILSVRC2012 and everything as explained in the *inception tutorial* in tensorflow but I can not pass this read_and_decode function. The problem lies in image.set_shape(). Does anyone knows what to do? And whats the purpose of set_shape() here?

```
def read_and_decode(filename_queue):
  reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
  _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
  features = tf.parse_single_example(
    serialized_example,
    features={
        'image_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
    })
  image = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw'], tf.uint8)
  image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) * (1. / 255) - 0.5

  # Here comes the error line
  image.set_shape([None, None, 3])

  label = tf.cast(features['label'], tf.int32)

  return image, label
```

Error log:

```
  File "./grasp_detection.py", line 49, in read_and_decode
  image.set_shape([None, None, 3])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-
  packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 425, in set_shape
  self._shape = self._shape.merge_with(shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-
  packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 585, in 
  merge_with
    (self, other))
  ValueError: Shapes (?,) and (?, ?, 3) are not compatible
```

**EDIT: Solved**
First I programmed it without `set_shape` but I got the error `ValueError: All shapes must be fully defined`. I knew that that in the *inception tutorial* from tensorflow all the images where preprocessed and had the same defined shape (unkonown to me). I thought that by finding the shape here in stackaoverflow and using the `set_shape` the problem of `read_and_decode` would be solved. Later I had to reshape the images to fit my model.

The natural and best way to pursue this was to reshape the images in `read_and_decode`, as pointed out also in comments. For everyone interested the working `read_and_decode` looks like this:

```
def read_and_decode(filename_queue):
  reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
  _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
  features = tf.parse_single_example(
      serialized_example,
      features={
          'image_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
          'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
      })
  image = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw'], tf.uint8)
  image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) * (1. / 255) - 0.5
  image_shape = tf.stack([IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, 3])
  image = tf.reshape(image, image_shape)
  label = tf.cast(features['label'], tf.int32)
  return image, label
```

Any suggestion or critique is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you just want to reshape the Tensor? If so, use [tf.reshape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape) (not with `None`s, but with integers or Tensors describing the new shape). The error you see is because `set_shape` is only there to more accurately describe the (static) shape of the Tensor; it doesn't/can't change it (and so throws an error if the shape "refinement" disagrees with the current shape information).

Answer (score 0):

One possible issue:

Did you feed shape in image.set_shape() ? It should be like

```
image.set_shape([image_height,image_width,nchannels]) or 
image.set_shape([None,None,nchannels])
```

Could you post the error log ?

Comment: I don't know the height, width and channels of the images as they were preprocessed by the _inception_ tutorial. I have tried the 'set_shape([None, None, 3])' with the errors shown in my question.

Comment: could you provide me the link which inception code you're following ?

Comment: [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception) is the tf tutorial that I followed. I used it just to preprocess the images.

Comment: could you try to print shape of image: print(image.get_shape()) before set_shape()?

Comment: I have tried also: 'features = tf.parse_single_example(
      serialized_example,
      features={
        'height': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        'width': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        'image_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string))' and then used this in set_shape; no results.

Comment: were you able to find shape of image after decode_raw ??

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to answer your question. Yes I tried it and it gave me a '(?,)' as an answer. Thx for your time.

Comment: Could you try to follow this link to write and read TFRecords : http://warmspringwinds.github.io/tensorflow/tf-slim/2016/12/21/tfrecords-guide/

Comment: Thats what I have found too. As i skimmed it, looked pretty promising. I will give it a try later. Thx

Comment: The link was very helpfull. It was worth the careful reading.